# SQL select latest record revisions in one of three language supplied in order of preference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, internationalization

So, I've got a table structure in SQL Server 2005 that has the following composite primary keys:

- `Id int`
- `Culture char(5)` (eg: en-US, en-GB etc...)
- `Created datetime`

The `User` table has `PrimaryCulture` and `SecondaryCulture` columns representing the users language preferences. The `Application` table contains a single `Culture` column representing the default language for the app.

I want a statement that will give me the latest revisions in one of the users choice of languages if available and the application default if not. I'm thinking along the lines of nested `COALESCE` statements eg: `COALESCE(CulturePrimary, COALESCE(CultureSecondary, CultureDefault))`.

This is what I've tried so far (it doesn't work, but I can't see why not):

```
SELECT
    d.Id,
    COALESCE(p.Title, COALESCE(s.Title, d.Title)) Title,
    COALESCE(p.[Description], COALESCE(s.[Description], d.[Description])) [Description]
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) Row,
        Id,
        Title,
        [Description]
    FROM Project WHERE Culture = 'en-US') d --DefaultCulture
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) Row,
        Id, 
        Title,
        [Description]
    FROM Project WHERE Culture = 'en-AU') p --PrimaryCulture
    ON p.Id = d.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) Row,
        Id, 
        Title,
        [Description]
    FROM Project WHERE Culture = 'en-GB') s --SecondaryCulture
    ON s.Id = d.Id
WHERE d.Row = 1
AND p.Row = 1
AND s.Row = 1
```

UPDATE:

So thanks @Martin, the problem was the final WHERE clause. Here's the solution:

```
SELECT
    x.Id,
    COALESCE(p.Title, s.Title, d.Title) Title,
    COALESCE(p.Description, s.Description, d.Description) [Description],
    COALESCE(p.Culture, s.Culture, d.Culture) Culture
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM Project) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) Row, Id, Title, [Description], Culture
    FROM Project WHERE Culture = 'en-US') d ON d.Id = x.Id AND d.Row = 1 --DefaultCulture
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) Row, Id, Title, [Description], Culture
    FROM Project WHERE Culture = 'en-AU') p ON p.Id = x.Id AND p.Row = 1 --PrimaryCulture
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) Row, Id, Title, [Description], Culture
    FROM Project WHERE Culture = 'en-GB') s ON s.Id = x.Id AND s.Row = 1 --SecondaryCulture
```

Comment: the way it is currently written, nesting the coalesce statements isn't doing anything. one coalesce with the 3 parameters will give the same result

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I had no idea that coalesce would take more than 2 arguments. Any idea why the joins do nothing?

Comment: i suspect it's because you have 'and' clauses as part of your where clause for the tables that can return nulls (i.e. it needs to bring back a record from each table to return anything)

Comment: Cheers @Martin that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work:

```
case 
    when coalesce(p.[Description], s.[Description]) is null then d.[Description]
    else coalesce(p.[Description], s.[Description])
end as [Description]
```

Edit: hmmm, a second reading of this answer reminds me never to attempt sql after a long day :P